# Find the sum of floors of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $a,b,c$ be the roots of
$$f(x)=x^3+x^2-5x-1$$
What is the value of the following?
$$\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor+\lfloor c\rfloor$$

Comment: Why i add my answer??

Comment: The roots of this function are very complicated. The only way to realize where the roots are, is to substitute numbers, and check where there is a sign change. For example, $f(2)=1$ and $f(1)<0$, so there's a root between $1$ and $2$. Proceed lkewise.

Comment: The significant of this sign$?

Comment: Between two points where the sign changes, a root is present. By the way, the answer below does your job.

Comment: The $ symbols indicate you can use MathJax in between. E.g. `$x=2$` produces $x=2$.

Answer (score 3):

If it weren't for the floor functions, you could use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas). Right now, the easiest way it to look at the graph of the function, which shows you that the roots lie between -3 and -2, between -1 and 0, and between 1 and 2. That means that the floors of these roots are -3, -1 and 1, and adding them up gives the result: -3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$x^3+x^2-5x-1=0$ is a cubic equation  whose roots are $x=a,b,c$

drawing graph of $f(x) =x^3+x^2-5x-1$

$f'(x) = 3x^2+2x-5$ and $f''(x) = 6x+2$

now local maximum, minimum $f'(x)=0$

so $\displaystyle x = \frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4+60}}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{-2 \pm 8}{6} = 1,-\frac{5}{3}$

so $f''(1) = 8>0$ . so $x=1$ is a point of local minimum and $\displaystyle f''(-\frac{5}{3})<0$

is a point of local maximum

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-5x-1

so one root of $f(x) = 0$ lie between $-3$ to $-2$ and one is $-1$ to $0$ and other is $1$ to $2$

so $\lfloor a \rfloor = -3$ and $\lfloor b \rfloor = -1$ and $\lfloor c \rfloor  = 1$

so $\lfloor a \rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor+\lfloor c \rfloor = -3-1+1 = -3$

Comment: Very very thnx Glorfindel